# External Email from Newsletter Mailing Fails

Tags: civimail

I have set the Outbound mailer to mail(), SMTP seems to really be problematic.

I am successful in the following:
Contacts | New eMail
Administer | Settings - Outbound Mail | Save & Send Test email

All go into the inbox of the intended external email address.

From Joomla, all the email functionality is working as well.

I am unsuccessful in being able to send a newsletter from the Mailings | Draft Unscheduled Mailings area,

I get a generic message, Error in call to Mailing_send_test : sendmail returned error code 1

This only happens if I send it to an outbound email (email addresses within the hosting provider work)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still interested - what version of Civi are you running? And you have selected PHP mail() as your mailer so it is odd that sendmail is referenced in the error msg. 
I can just say that I have Civi 4.7.20 (for WP though I think that isn't relevant). System outbound mail is set to mail().  I only got email to work by adding back check for blank CC/BCC that was in older versions of CRM/Utils/Mail.php
'Save and send test email' works b/c it doesn't go to Utils/Mail it just instantiates its own PEAR Mailer and sends a header with just 'to','from''subject' and 'message'